# Angular - Update a tag in an imported template

Tags: angular, templates

I have an application in which I need to import a component in another one, and use the imported component template.

Is it possible to change an HTML tag in the parent template. For example:

I have a component "component-a", with this template:

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
```

In component "component-b" template, I would like to add attributes to the input tag above. "component-b" template example:

```
<h3>Enter your name:</h3>
<component-a></component-a>
```

How to update the input tag? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. For an instance lets take the `value` attribute of `<input>`

```
// component-a
@Component({
selector:'component-a',
template:'<input type="text" value={{inputData}} class="form-control">'
})
export class ComponentA{
@Input()
inputData:string;
}

// component-b
<component-a [inputData]="'hello'"></component-a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to add new attributes in component-b that don't exist in component-a?

Comment: You can use multiple `@Input()` variables in `component-a` so that you can pass values from component-b to all of those in component-a. eg: `<component-a [firstAttribute]='somevalue' [secondAttr]='otherval'...`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand that it don't add any attributes if I not specify any value for inputData.

Comment: What if I want to add [(ngModel)] and #name ?

Comment: You can add `[(ngModel)] anytime its just try to figure out the use of it. `[(ngModel)]` if for two-way binding and its just within the component. This transfers data between the class and the template. for an instance `<input type='text' [(ngModel)]='someVariable'>` will bind `someVariable` value with the input text. since 2 way binding, the changes done to `someVariable` from either the component or the template, they are reflected on both of themselves. Basically, you cannot pass data with [(ngModel)] between components but inside a component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an input variable in component-b `@Input() modifyInput: boolean = false;`.

Now you can add attributes based on the boolean:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [attr.name]="modifyInput ? 'Modified' : 'unmodified'"/>
```